# Game stuttering/fps drops on PC

Tags: performance, gpu, gaming

I've been facing a frustrating problem while playing Gta V, Red Dead Redemption 2, and Red Dead Online. The games frequently stutters/fps drops where the GPU usage tanks from 25/70%-4% (even using a different gpu and onboard graphics).

No matter where in the game I am, menu/ingame/settings. I've tried every troubleshooting steps like updating drivers, different gpu, removing one of my ram sticks, re-installing windows, every fix you could find online, but the issue persists.

System Specifications:

- **OS**: Windows 11 22H2 build 22621.2792
- **CPU**: AMD Ryzen 9 7950X
- **GPU**: RTX 2080 Super (different GPU: RTX 2060)
- **RAM**: Kingston Fury DDR5 2x32GB
- **Storage**: Game is on M.2 OS is on a SSD (also have like 3 more regular HDDs)
- **PSU**: XPG CORE Reactor 850Watt 80 Plus Gold modular, I got around July 10th, 2021.
- **Motherboard**: Asus TUF Gaming B650-Plus wifi BIOS ver.0823

This issue also only happens on the game listed prior. I have been unable to find a connection to these games except for gta and rdr (since they're both rockstar games). Every other game, even AAA games like horizon zero dawn, Lies of P, or Call of duty. Don't have this issue.

I'm seeking advice or any suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem or knows of potential fixes?

Comment: Are there entries in Event Viewer from around the time of the stuttering that can clue you in? Increased hard drive activity? Changes in network traffic patterns?

Comment: @music2myear I tried to spot anything in event viewer at the time of the drops, but wasn't able to find anything at the time of the drop.

No changes in network, i did notice a totally different drive that doesnt have the OS or games on it spike at the same time - I set all drives that werent the game/os drive to offline, and it still happened.

the only thing I found that was constant was the gpu usage drops, as stated in the post, and it isnt a gpu problem as it still happens with my onboard and different gpu.

Comment: Do you have gsync enabled? If so you may try turning it off and seeing if the issue persists afterwards. My guess is the GPU utilization drops because of the stutter, rather than being a cause.

Comment: @NateW I do not have G-SYNC enabled, my monitor does not support it

Comment: I had a similar issue a long time ago. Replacing the motherboard did the trick for me.

Comment: Have you tried using software to monitor your 3,3v,5v, and 12v rails on your power supply.

Comment: @cybernard Im unsure of an application to monitor power supply volts, but this does only happen on those 4 games, every other one is fine, even super intensive like COD, so i dont believe Fall guys would use more power and cause drops.. if thats what you meant

Comment: @DrZoo was it with the motherboard I currently have/the same games? or the same situation, like 3-4 games stutter, rest are fine? I could possibly get a motherboard from the store to test then return it if it doesnt work.

Comment: Mine was not specifically those games, but it occurred with certain more graphically intense games, like the ones you listed. It started out with stuttering and brief GPU drops. It eventually got to a point to where the game would suddenly crash. I know it's somewhat of an annoyance to swap in a new board to see if it resolves the issue, but you've gone through a good amount of troubleshooting steps to no avail.

Comment: @DrZoo ah okay, yeah its weird cause Fall guys is not graphically intense at all. but it happens. on my old motherboard/cpu/ram (I a few months ago actually upgraded) they ran well i believe, except for squads, but that was a cpu thing. im going to try a new mb tomorrow, if it doesnt work its easy to return :D

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the original poster purchased a new motherboard which fixes the issue but is not really a troubleshooting solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to @DrZoo , My problem was fixed!

Just replacing the motherboard worked to fix the stutter on the games listed.

Thank you everyone for all your help!

Comment: BTW you listed a very low BIOS revision number on the other MB. They removed BIOS updates below a certain revision from heir site for what look like stability reasons. https://www.asus.com/motherboards-components/motherboards/tuf-gaming/tuf-gaming-b650-plus/helpdesk_bios?model2Name=TUF-GAMING-B650-PLUS

Comment: @Yorik The night before replacing the board, I updated it to the newest bios, 1811. the issue still occurred, apologies as I should have probably added that.